# Android -Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvide

Tags: java, android, uri, android-contentresolver

In my application i have requirement to after selected file from gallery user can remove selected file, but i could not found any suitable solution for how to remove selected URI, if i converted it to file and deleted it, then file deleted permanently from file storage also any suggestion
**UPDATE:**
i try below code also but its given exception 
"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference"

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        uri = data.getData();
        //String filePath = getRealPathFromURIPath(uri, CreateInquiry.this);
        String filePath = FileUtils.getRealPath(getApplicationContext(),uri);
        File file = new File(filePath);
        remove(uri);
      AttachedFileDao dao=new AttachedFileDao();
      dao.setFileName(file.getName());
      dao.setFileUri(filePath);


        attachedFile.add(dao);

        fileAdpter=new AttachedFileAdpter(attachedFile,getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(fileAdpter);




    }
}

public boolean remove(final Uri uri) {
    try {
        context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
        return true;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

after getting the result in onactivity result i just want to remove remove selected file path data, so if user selected wrong file then he able to deleted the file without upload.
**update 2**
while calling calling getcontentResolver i am getting security exception like

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2FCSP.pdf from pid=22959, uid=10115 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()

but i added all permission any solution for that.

Comment: your requirement is not clear , can you post some of your code here .

Comment: @Danialclarc i just want to delete file from  uri  file path  but here after deleting the file its also remove from sd card.